# Why would 'data:' be a script-src for CSP?

Tags: content-security-policy

I've seen the following Content Security Violation in my server's logs. **When would there be a 'data:' type script-src?** Isn't 'data:' only for e.g. base64 encoded images?

```
CSP violation! 
    { 'csp-report':
        { 'blocked-uri': 'data:',
        'document-uri': 'https://certsimple.com/blog/domain-validated-ssl',
        'original-policy': longPolicyGoesHere,
        referrer: '',
        'violated-directive': 'script-src https://example.com https://use.typekit.net \'unsafe-inline\' https://js.stripe.com \'unsafe-eval\' https://platform.twitter.com https://cdn.mxpnl.com https://syndication.twitter.com' } }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`data:` is for base64 encoded, embedded data. While the most popular usage is to encode images into stylesheets to reduce the number of requests, that is not the only use. The URI scheme can be used for scripts like the following:

```
<script src="data:application/javascript;charset=utf-8;base64,YWxlcnQoJ1hTUycpOw=="></script>
```

Also available on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sboe8z4u/).

The report you're seeing is legitimate, something is attempting to inject arbitrary javascript into your page using the Data URI scheme to obfuscate what it's doing. While this could be reflective of an issue in your application, it's more likely going to be a rogue browser extension that's either malicious and trying to do sneaky things or [benign and very badly coded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor).

Comment: Thanks! The other CSP warnings have also been browser extension related so that seems common. Could you add an example of what JS using a data URI would look like and I'll mark this as the answer? It's not very common so I'm having trouble finding examples.

Comment: Love the link to Hanlon's razor! :)

Comment: How would you update the policy to allow this? Our website uses a plug-in which, according to the "source-file" property, appears to be the culprit.

Comment: If your plugin requires images, you would do something like `img-src: data:`. For scripts, you can do `script-src data:`. The colon at the end of data matters. It is noteworthy that this will reduce the security of your application, but it's better to have a lax CSP policy than no CSP policy at all.